# GNU plots_Plotting histograms from given set of values against the number of their occurances

Tags: gnuplot

How can we plot a histogram from a csv file containing all data into a single column. I need to plot those values vs the number of times they get repeated.

Comment: Please add information about the operative system under which you use gnuplot using [this link](http://superuser.com/posts/930167/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a wide used trick to build histogram in gnuplot. If your data is in the file `mydata.csv`, you can try something like

```
binwidth=1                          # here you can set the bin width 
bin(x,width)=width*floor(x/width)   # here the binning function
plot "mydata.csv" using (bin($1,binwidth)):(1.0) smooth freq with boxes
```

So you are building your histogram choosing the bin width.
In a more fine way you can try what below [as suggested for example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19596160/3569208)

```
Min = 1.0  # where binning starts
Max = 12.0 # where binning ends
n = 11 # the number of bins
width = (Max-Min)/n # binwidth is evaluates to 1.0
bin(x,width) = width*(floor((x-Min)/width)+0.5) + Min
plot "mydata.csv" using (bin($1,width)):(1.0) smooth freq with boxes
```

Comment: Now, I am able to plot Histogram, but need to normalize the number of occurances.I took help from another forum to define a variable sum, But I am not able to plot normalized values. I am using these commands.
set ylabel 'f/n_f'
set xlabel 'k_{ij}^{n}/k_{0}^{n}'
set xtics 0.2
set ytics 2
binwidth = 0.1
set boxwidth binwidth
sum = 0
s(x)          = ((sum=sum+1), 0)
bin(x, width) = width*floor(x/width) + binwidth/2.0
plot "mydata.csv" u (bin($1, binwidth)):(1.0/(binwidth*sum)) smooth freq w boxes

Comment: As you can see it often results  not so clean to post many lines of code in a comment. BTW a multiple question should be [split in different posts as different questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts). This will help other people with similar doubt. :)

Comment: From what I understand you never _call_ `s(x)` on your datafile with some other plot, and so you did not update the value of `sum`. Under Linux or OS you can set it with a system call to `wc -l mydata.csv` or with a call to `awk`... Do another question and it will be simpler for me to give you an answer.